# Testing RxJava: AdvanceTime not working in simple deferred flowable

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a very simple function that defers a value with a given delay:

```
Flowable.defer<Effect> { Flowable.just(Effect.Success) as Publisher<out Effect> }
  .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .subscribeOn(computationScheduler)
  .observeOn(mainScheduler)
```

I try to test it advancing the time in the computationScheduler like this:

```
  private val mainScheduler = Schedulers.trampoline()
  private val computationScheduler = TestScheduler()

  @Test
  fun solve() {
    val testObserver = actor.invoke(Action.Solve).test()

    computationScheduler.advanceTimeBy(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    testObserver.assertValues(Effect.Success)
  }
```

Without the delay, this just works, but it seems I can't manage to advance the time properly.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the javadocs of the delay method you are calling:

> This version of {@code delay} operates by default on the {@code
>   computation} {@link Scheduler}.

So your code is not working because the delay method is using a different computation scheduler than the one you are subscribing to.

In order to fix it you have to either pass your TestScheduler `computationScheduler` to the delay method:

```
Flowable.defer<Effect> { Flowable.just(Effect.Success) as Publisher<out Effect> }
    .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, computationScheduler)
    ...
```

Or set the computation scheduler handler of the rxjava lib:

```kotlin
RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { computationScheduler }
```

Comment: God I can't belive I did that mistake. Thank you a lot for your response!